# Split a column in to two columns bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Input

```
1st row 
2nd row
3rd row

4th row
5th row
6th row
```

Desired Output

```
1st row 4th row
2nd row 5th row
3rd row 6th row
```

I tried `column` it doesn't seem to work.
I am trying to do it with out a bash script if possible.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { cnt=1 } /^$/ { cnt++;next } { if (cnt==1) { map1[cnt1++]=$0 } else { map2[cnt2++]=$0 } } END { for (i in map1) { print map1[i]" "map2[i]}}' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
             cnt=1                                            # Initialise a column counter to 1
           } 
      /^$/ { 
             cnt++;                                            # When there is a blank line, increment the cnt variable
             next                                              # Skip to the next line
           } 
           { 
             if (cnt==1) {    
               map1[cnt1++]=$0                                     # If cnt is equal to 1, set an array map1, with an index as an incrementing counter (cnt1) and the value as the actual data on the line ($0)
             } 
             else { 
               map2[cnt2++]=$0                                     # If cnt not equal to 1, follow the same logic as before but use array map2 instead
             } 
           } 
       END { 
             for (i in map1) { 
               print map1[i]" "map2[i]                          # Loop through map1, printing the entries as well as the corresponding index entries for map2
             };
           }' file
```

Comment: Apologies. I miss understood your question initially. Try with the amendments,

Comment: They are separated by a blank line , although i don't know if this matters but the size of my file is more than 2000 lines , with only one blank line separating my column

Comment: Now it works!! Thanks! I was hoping for a simpler and cleaner solution with out scripting but it seems i have no other choice.

Comment: No worries. If the solution meets your needs, please take the time to up vote and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to do it with out a bash script if possible. Thanks in advance!

The `pr` utility can do that without the need for scripting, not saying that scripting is not needed but there exist a tool just for that purpose.

```
pr -t2 file.txt
```

To use a space to separate the columns.

```
pr -t2 -s' ' file.txt
```

See the man pages for `pr` for more info.